# How Can i find a point on a graph when i only have 1 point, angel, and units(distance)

Tags: trigonometry

How Can i find a point on a graph when i only have 1 point, angel, and units(distance)?

Please consider me a novice with your answer? have been about 15 years since i was at school. It took me like an 30 minutes yesterday to find out how to calculate the distance between 2 points so...

here is an image to demonstrate what i am after:

[image: What is Y2,X2]

How can i find Y2 and X2 ?

Thanks

Comment: I would ask the angel --- they are usually very helpful.

Comment: Ah.. i had it misspelled bah

Answer (score 1):

Treat $m = \tan(53^{\circ})$ as the slope of the function.  By the point-slope form,

$$\begin{aligned}
y - y_0 &= m(x - x_0)\\
y + 3 &= \tan(53)(x + 5)\\
y &= \tan(53)x + 5\tan(53) - 3
\end{aligned}$$

Then, by the elementary distance formula,

$$\begin{aligned}
d &= \sqrt{(x - x_1)^2 + (y - y_1)^2}\\
7 &= \sqrt{(x + 5)^2 + (y + 3)^2}\\
49 &= (x + 5)^2 + (y + 3)^2\\
49 &= (x + 5)^2 + (\tan(53)x + 5\tan(53) - 3 + 3)^2\\
49 &= (x + 5)^2 + (\tan(53)x + 5\tan(53))^2
\end{aligned}$$

With some algebra, you should get $x \approx -0.787$ and $y \approx 5.591$, which resembles the point on top-right of the given point (though the points and lines are not drawn to scale).  Another solution can also be $x \approx -9.213$ and $y \approx -5.591$.

Comment: Getting my daughter to help me solve that as there are some thing i have no clue what they mean.

Comment: what does tan means ? and the x0?

Comment: "tan" means the tangent of the angle. If you don't know the trigonometric functions (tangent, cosine and the rest), I don't think you'll understand any solution to this problem.

Comment: well its seems alot more complicated then distance between 2 points

Comment: There is no law saying different problems must all be equally hard.

Comment: Only now i got this calculation . however the issue is like you said there could be 2 solutions, i only need 1 which is from the point and onward, not backward